# RelayCommand stops working after a while

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, relaycommand

I am facing some problems using GalaSoft's RelayCommand.

I have a **NextCommand** property that works, but only several times.

Afterwards, it stops working completely.

You can try this out with the sample project:

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=65828891881629261404

The behaviour is as follows:

1. **NextCommand**:

   1. pops all items until the active index
   2. if there are less than 50 items left, pushes 1 new item
   3. marks new item as active
2. **BackCommand**:

   1. moves the active index back by 1 position

Steps to replicate:

1. the '+' (OemPlus) key has been bound to NextCommand
2. the '-' (OemMinus) key has been bound to BackCommand
3. Hold the '+' key until the list stops growing (50 items limit)
4. Hold the '-' key until the first item in the list is the active
5. Repeat

The number of repetitions needed (to replicate the bug) is inconsistent.

Sometimes I get it after 4 repetitions; other times up till 9.

[image]

```
// Items Collection
public class ItemCollection : ViewModelBase
{
    // List of Items
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Item> _items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
    }

    // Constructor
    public ItemCollection()
    {
        BackCommand = new RelayCommand(
                () =>
                {
                    // Go to previous page
                    var index = Items.IndexOf(ActiveItem);
                    if (index > 0)
                    {
                        ActiveItem = Items[index - 1];
                    }
                },
                () => ActiveItem != null && Items.IndexOf(ActiveItem) > 0);
    }

    // Back command
    public RelayCommand BackCommand { get; set; }

    // Next command
    public RelayCommand NextCommand { get; set; }

    // The currently-active item
    private Item _activeItem;
    public Item ActiveItem
    {
        get { return _activeItem; }
        set
        {
            Set(() => ActiveItem, ref _activeItem, value);
        }
    }
}

// Item
public class Item : ViewModelBase
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

When I stepped into the RelayCommand's code, the execute action's **isAlive** flag was false. But I can't seem to figure out how that might happen.

Comment: +1 for your nice animated Gif explaining your issue.

Comment: I don't see where is `NextCommand` instantiated in your code. The problem could be there (something what disable it).

Comment: In other words, we need to see what `NextCommand` is

Comment: Your sample project is not available anymore

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two words: **Garbage Collector**

In your example project--which you should post the relevant bits of to make your question future-proof--you set the `DataContext` on your window like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var logic  = new LogicObject();
        DataContext = logic.Collection;
    }
}
```

Because nothing else retains a reference to the `LogicObject` created here, it will be collected at the next opportunity.

The command stops functioning because in `LogicObject`, you set the `NextCommand` of the `ItemCollection` to use private members of the soon-to-be-collected `LogicObject`:

```
public class LogicObject
{
    public LogicObject()
    {
        Collection = new ItemCollection();
        Collection.NextCommand = new RelayCommand(AddItem, CanAddItem);
        AddItem();
    }

    private bool CanAddItem()
    {
        // snip...
    }

    private void AddItem()
    {
        // snip...
    }
}
```

Once `LogicObject` is collected, the command can no longer work because it no longer has references to valid methods (`AddItem` and `CanAddItem`).  This is why the `isAlive` field on both of the `RelayCommand`'s weak references to the methods is false.

You can fix this by just hanging on to the `LogicObject`, or by moving the `AddItem` and `CanAddItem` methods into the collection.

---

To get in the spirit of GIFs for this question, here's one that shows the button stop working as soon as a Gen 0 collection occurs.

[image: Desktop capture showing button failing when GC occurs]

Comment: I see it now. Always knew that RelayCommand uses WeakActions and WeakReferences, but still managed to miss the part where my LogicObject wasn't referenced anywhere else. Thanks for the answer! (and great gif btw)

Comment: As of MVVMLight 5.4.0 you can use the `keepTargetAlive` constructor parameter to keep closures from being garbage-collected:  http://www.mvvmlight.net/doc/weakaction.cshtml

Answer (score 1):

why dont you simply use the methods from ICollectionView? there you have:

- MoveCurrentTo
- MoveCurrentToFirst
- MoveCurrentToLast
- MoveCurrentToNext
- MoveCurrentToPrevious
- and other nice stuff

something like this

```
 private ICollectionView MyView {get;set;}


 this.MyView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this._items);


 if (!this.MyView.IsCurrentBeforeFirst)
 {
     this.MyView.MoveCurrentToPrevious();
 }
```

Comment: hi blindmeis. I wasn't really looking for collection operations. I just happened to name the sample classes ItemCollection and Item. The key part of the code is the NextCommand property, that is configurable by its caller.