# GalaSoft MvvmLight RelayCommand stops working when accessing closure

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light, commandbinding

I struggle using the GalaSoft.MvvmLight.RelayCommand. All is working fine until i try to Access a closure. I don't get any error or log output.

This Code is working:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                var iTemp = i;

                var command = new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("executed");

                    Debug.WriteLine(this);

                    // Debug.WriteLine(iTemp);
                });
                Commands[i.ToString()] = command;
                children.Add(dataTemplateCreator.BuildButtonWithCommand(0, gridRow, $"Commands[{i}]", i.ToString()));

                gridRow++;
            }
```

As soon as i remove the Comment the Command is no longer executed.
Has anyone seen this behavior before?

I also tried an easier

Works:

```
Execute = new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            Value += 3;

        });
```

Stops working:

```
 var incValue = 3;

            Execute = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                Value += incValue;

            });
```

Comment: I just ran into this same bug. Definitely should be reported if it hasn't already.

Comment: Didn't see a bug report, so I added one: https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7721. If you'd like to see this fixed, please upvote the bug. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You've undoubtedly solved this or moved on, but your problem is garbage collection.

The problem is described in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25869087/1110311) and the solution is described in this [MVVMLight documentation item](http://www.mvvmlight.net/doc/weakaction.cshtml).

In short: The command action and enable function you pass to `RelayCommand` are stored with weak references, so unless something besides the `RelayCommand` is holding onto them, they will be garbage-collected at some point. The solution is to use the `keepTargetAlive` constructor parameter if your action or enable function are closures.