# Inconsistent behavior: MVVM RelayCommandWPF with closure capturing local variable

Tags: c#, closures, mvvm-light

I'm trying to understand some odd behavior I'm seeing with a MVVM RelayCommand whose action is a closure capturing a local variable.

Minimum viable code sample:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public RelayCommand DoIt { get; }

        int i = 0;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            DoIt = new RelayCommand( () =>
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine( "doing it!" );
                button.Content = (++i).ToString();
            } );

            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Hit me" Command="{Binding DoIt, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
</Window>
```

When you tap the "Hit me" button, the label changes to a number which increments for every subsequent tap.

Since `i` is only used by the `RelayCommand` action, I want to move the declaration to the constructur as a local variable. But when I do, I get very odd behavior: The command either won't fire at all, or fires once and then stops.

Interestingly enough, if I nix the `RelayCommand` and wire the closure to the button's `Click` event, it works no matter where I define `i`. So it must be something in the way `RelayCommand` is handling the closure.

Any guesses?

Comment: Can you grab the source code and step through it in the debugger? https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(PCL)/Command/RelayCommand.cs

Comment: Also, can you try creating a delay timed action to run this on the UI thread and see what happens: ((RelayCommand) DoIt).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the closure passed to the command gets garbage-collected eventually. Credit to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25869087/1110311) and this [MVVMLight documentation item](http://www.mvvmlight.net/doc/weakaction.cshtml).

The command action and enable function you pass to `RelayCommand` are stored with weak references, so unless something besides the `RelayCommand` is holding onto them, they will be garbage-collected at some point. The solution is to use the `keepTargetAlive` constructor parameter if your action or enable function are closures.